# About Stackwalking and GCInfo

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr

As you may know, GC roots are listed in GCInfo by JIT and EE depends on this info when it reports roots to GC. As far as i understand, when managed thread is suspended, EE uses value of EIP to find GC info. My question is, what will happen when you detour/hook a method? Or what happens if you skip unmanaged transition part and directly call unmanaged methods as if its managed (and possibly you dont access/change any managed resources within it)?

Comment: `EE uses value of EIP to find GC info` -  what gave you that impression?

Comment: because gcinfo is based on instruction offsets.

Comment: I would say: *When managed thread is eventually suspended, EE uses current EIP to provide the GC roots"*. Interesting questions but I would need some more context - how exactly you would like to hook a method? And, how exactly you would like to skip  directly call unmanaged method?

Comment: Hi Konrad, i was reading your book before this question came to my mind :) Say hook is primitive hook, writing jump instruction into the beginning address of method returned by GetFunctionPointer call. Skipping could be achieved by jumping or misusing calli IL instruction. There are other ways though like changing internal method pointer of delegate or replacing method address, or providing direct method address to unmanaged method as callback.

Comment: Nice to hear you've read it! In short, I would say both `calli` and `GetFunctionPointer` are not so *direct* as they may seem, they provide/use stubs to track managed/unmanaged code transition. Thanks to that unmanaged frames are just ignored (but arguments are not). If you misuse something (magic direct `jmp`s) you will mess up internal Frames chain and probably something will blow up. Have you seen [CLR Threading Overview](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/docs/design/coreclr/botr/threading.md)?

Comment: but what if you use calli in managed form with unmanaged function pointer or replace internal delegate pointer with unmanaged one? other than that GetFunctionPointer seems pretty direct to me because it appears in asm of jitted code. regarding to jmp,  ive seen many hooking libraries achieving this with direct jump, if they are doing wrong, how official ms detour library do this properly?

Comment: Interesting, could you provide links to those hooking libraries? I'm going to blog post about those exact topics soon, so I'll probably copy-paste an answer here too.

Comment: With quick search on google ive came accross those:
https://github.com/wledfor2/PlayHooky/blob/7c2564eceae01dfe2457c91425d9af2a938e77bc/HookManager.cs#L170

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra

Harmony also does that way. Other than modfying IL there is no way i think which is only valid for managed to managed hooks. And ive read there are requests for new Function Pointer C# language feature that, for fast methods they could skip unmanaged transition.
Can you give me quick answers before i wait for your blog post?